# How to disable users from editing billing address in WooCommerce checkout?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there a way to disable users from editing their billing address in checkout page?

I'm trying to achieve a state where the user can see the current billing address but cannot change it without contacting the shop admin. The user can only change the shipping address for the order. Both addresses should still be attached to the order.

My current solution was to remove the fields completely by using the `woocommerce_billing_fields` hook and print the billing address fields as static html instead but then the billing address doesn't appear in the order at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found a solution after Slack conversation. It is possible to remove the fields from checkout by unsetting them in `woocommerce_billing_fields` hook and then re-adding the values again to the order from users profile with `woocommerce_checkout_posted_data` hook.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'fill_order_billing_details' );

function fill_order_billing_details( $data ) {
  $customer_id = get_current_user_id();

  $data['billing_first_name'] = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', true );
  $data['billing_last_name']  = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', true );
  $data['billing_company']    = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_company', true );
  $data['billing_country']    = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_country', true );
  $data['billing_address_1']  = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_address_1', true );
  $data['billing_address_2']  = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_address_2', true );
  $data['billing_city']       = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_city', true );
  $data['billing_state']      = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_state', true );
  $data['billing_postcode']   = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_postcode', true );
  $data['billing_phone']      = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );
  $data['billing_email']      = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_email', true );

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: How can I do that for certain user roles only?

Comment: Not a bad idea..